# Alternative for from_unixtime in GENERATED ALWAYS query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Unfortunately, MySQL/MariaDB no longer supports using `from_unixtime` in Stored Generated Always columns, I am trying to generate values in a column automatically from another column that contains timestamp values. I have this

```
ALTER TABLE messages 
ADD COLUMN only_date DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS from_unixtime(timestamp_column, '%Y-%M-%D') STORED;
```

Can someone please help with an alternative that works? Thanks.

Comment: why from_unixtime at all? what's wrong with now(), curdate(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: *`.. from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%M-%D') ..`* - does `timestamp` is column name? if so then quote it (the best way - rename it).

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am not getting the current timestamp, the user chooses a date it stores in the db as a timestamp, but now I want to have another column that fetches the timestamp (that the user chose) from the db column and converts it to plain date

Comment: @Akina I renamed it, thanks.

Comment: The feature was removed because it relied on session data (time zone) - Ticket [MDEV-21593](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21593). What time zone should the new `date` column use to do the conversion?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Europe/Sofia

Comment: I just tested it in MySQL 8.0.29. It works once I changed the format to `'%Y-%m-%d'`. I don't use MariaDB, so I didn't test that.